# Nginx Log the query header size or the cookies size

Tags: nginx

When you query headers are too big you get a 400 `Request Header Or Cookie Too Large` error.

It is hard to find into the log those kind of errors mixed with all 400 errors.

Is there a way to log the header size or cookie size for all queries ?

Or at least, is there a way to log why we get a 400 error ?

By the way I am not looking to increase the accepted size just to monitor the cookie size and catch relative error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using OpenResty, via the module [ngx_http_lua_module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module)

First generate the value using lua block into the server configuration

```
server {

    listen 80;

    set_by_lua_block $my_http_cookies_size {
        return ngx.var.http_cookie and string.len(ngx.var.http_cookie) or 0
    }
}
```

Then you can log it

```
log_format my_json escape=json
  '{'
    '"time": "$time_iso8601",'
    '"message": "$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] \\\"$request\\\" $status $body_bytes_sent \\\"$http_referer\\\" \\\"$http_user_agent\\\" $scheme $host $request_time \\\"$upstream_http_x_route_path\\\"",'
    '"duration": $request_time,'
    '"http": {'
      '"status_code": $status,'
      '"url": "$request_uri",'
      '"method": "$request_method",'
      '"referer": "$http_referer",'
      '"useragent": "$http_user_agent",'
      '"host": "$host",'
      '"scheme": "$scheme",'
      '"user": "$remote_user",'
      '"route": "$upstream_http_x_route_path",'
      '"forwarded_for": "$http_x_forwarded_for",'
      '"cookies_size": $mm_http_cookies_size'
    '},'
    '"network": {'
      '"bytes_written": $bytes_sent,'
      '"client": {'
        '"ip": "$remote_addr"'
      '},'
      '"geoip": {'
        '"country": {'
          '"iso_code": "$geoip_country_code",'
          '"name": "$geoip_country_name"'
        '},'
        '"region": {'
          '"name": "$geoip_region_name"'
        '},'
        '"city": {'
          '"name": "$geoip_city"'
        '},'
        '"location": {'
          '"lat": $log_latitude,'
          '"lon": $log_longitude'
        '}'
      '}'
    '}'
  '}';

access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log.json my_json;
```